# Programming Error "XXX is already defined in main(String[])"

Tags: java, arrays

My assignment is to Write a program to do the following:

Ask the user to enter a positive integer, n, from 2 to 100.
Declare 3 arrays called x, xsquared, xcubed, where each array can store up to 101 values.

- In array x, store the values of i from 1 to n in cells i from 1 to n.
- In array xsquared, store the values of i^2 from 1 to n in cells i from 1 to n.
- In array xcubed, store the values of i^3 from 1 to n in cells i from 1 to n.

Then use a “for” loop to compute the sums of the first n integers, n squared integers, and n cubed integers.

EG:  If user enters n = 5,  then  1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15;  1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25 = 55;
                1 + 8 + 27 + 64 + 125 = 225

Finally, verify that for a given value of n,  (n^2 + n + 1 )(n – 1) = n^3 - 1

In my program I seem to be getting an error stating

```
i is already defined in main(String[])
```

My program does not seem to sum anything or square anything.  Why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySquareCube
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    double[] numbers = new double[101];
    double sum = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter a number from 0 through 100");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = in.nextInt();

    for (int i : numbers)
    {
      sum = sum + i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
      numbers[i] = i*i;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the error?

```
for (int i : numbers)
```

At this point, `i` is already defined in `main(String[])`. It was defined here:

```
int i = in.nextInt();
```

If you can get the program to compile, @shantha points out that you're summing the numbers before you've initialized them from 0 to 100.

Note that `0 * 0 = 0`, and `0 + x = x`, so as a minor optimisation you can skip 0 and save yourself a `double`, and that `new double[101]` call will have a slightly nicer magic number in it.

Comment: Three times, if you count both "for" loops.

Comment: My in-built parser is quite intolerant to errors. It saw that one and stopped.

Comment: Still the sum is zero according to the code segments.(I commented on the question itself). There is a logical error too.

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to redefining the `int i` in those `for` loops. And I would like to point an issue of getting zero for your result after you fix the main issue.

The sum is zero as you sum double array defined in

```
double[] numbers = new double[101];
```

It is because primitive type `double` is initialized to zero by default. If you print the each elements value in the array `numbers` then every elements value should be zero.

By default the elements, you refer numbers[i], are initialized to zero.

So in the code

```
for (int i : numbers)
```

The `i` here is zero for every item in `numbers` array. (as each double primitive initialized default to zero )

If you initialize the `numbers` array properly with values other than default value or zero you can see the summation of the array elements.

Edited: If you change places of your for loop with each other the sum should work.
Like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
   numbers[i] = i*i;
}

for (int i : numbers)
{
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to use i in for-each loop and in usual for-loop, but it is already defined in

`int i = in.nextInt();`

so compiler argues.

Comment: I feel bad for Java developers if their compiler argues with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySquareCube {
public static void main(String[] args){
    double[] numbers = new double[101];
    double sum = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a number from 0 through 100");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = in.nextInt();
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
      sum = sum + j;
    }
    for (int c = 0; c < numbers.length; c++){
      numbers[c] = c*c;
    }
  }
}
```

I believe is what you are looking for.

Comment: -1 it's clearly not what "what (he is) looking for". "My program does not seem to sum anything or square anything. Why?" He wants to know why *his program* doesn't work.

Comment: Well I fixed it and showed teh correct result...

It is valid.

Comment: "Teacher, I keep getting these types of questions wrong. Why?" "The answer's six. There, I answered your question."

Comment: This is why it is impossible to get a rep on this site. Just because I am only 12 and haven't gone to university yet, apparently i can't answer without being downvoted. You are one of _those_ people now.

Comment: Geez dude... don't freak out.  Reputation builds up fast once you really get cooking. Downvoting subtracts two points and upvoting adds **10** points.  If you write an answer people like (and I'm certain you will), it'll take 5 downvotes to negate 1 up vote. And any downvote that a person does subtracts one point from their own reputation. So people don't downvote to be malicious.  They downvote to be helpful.  I've learned lots of things from my own downvoted answers.

Comment: Oh, and I +1'd you because you took the time and effort to try to re-code up a good solution.

Comment: It is generally felt for [tag:homework] questions that it is better to give an explanation than code.  Of course, I was the one that tagged this as homework based on "My assignment..", only 3 minutes before you posted a reply (which might not have been seen by you when you posted the answer).  Don't stress the rep., you'll get the hang of it.  All the best.

Comment: This program is not correct according to the original question. It does the summation of the double array. But in this code do the summation of loop variable.

Comment: @shantha - It would have the same effect if the loops were in the right order in the original question.

Comment: @todda.speot.is - The problem is original code `for (int i : numbers)` does not match with your code `for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++){`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @shantha You are right, it should be `sum += j * j` to have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. when compiling, there're two errors. First is the

   ```
   for(int i : numbers)

   ...

   for(int i = 0; ...)
   ```

   which indicates a duplicate variable of "i".

   Second is the

   ```
   for(int i : numbers)
   ```

   while "numbers" is array of double and "i" is int, which indicates a type mismatch.

   So the code could not even get compiled.

2 .You are required to declare 3 arrays. So just declare them. I just see 1 array in your code.

3 .Use the integer that user input. Use another counter to help computing, not "i" itself.

Try it yourself and come back if you encounter another problem.

PS: I suggest you use a good IDE such as Eclipse. It indicates you this kind of errors while editing.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ArraySquareCube {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    double[] numbers = new double[101];
    double sum = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a number from 0 through 100");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = in.nextInt();
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    sum = sum + j;
    System.out.println(sum);
    }

Comment: sorry for the very late reply. suffering from a bad web condition. what's these codes for? Does any new problems occur?